# using collective.z3cform.datagridfield with plone.app.registry and GenericSetup

Tags: python, plone, z3c.form, genericsetup

Plone 4.2.0.1, plone.app.registry 1.1, plone.supermodel 1.1.1, collective.z3cform.datagridfield 0.11

I am trying to use collective.z3cform.datagridfield for a plone.app.registry field but having trouble actually setting values for it. The documentation doesn't seem to say
much other than to use collective.z3cform.datagridfield.registry.DictRow for a Persistent version for the registry.

For reference, my class looks like this:

```
class IMySchema(form.Schema):
  code = schema.TextLine(title = _(u"Code"), required=False)
  name = schema.TextLine(title = _(u"Name"), required=False)

from collective.z3cform.datagridfield.registry import DictRow
class IMySettings(form.Schema):
  """ """
  form.widget(display_fields=DataGridFieldFactory)
  display_fields = schema.List(
                     title = _(u"Display Fields"),
                     description = _(u"The fields that will be displayed in view and edit pages"),
                     value_type=DictRow(title=_(u"Field"), schema=IMySchema),
                     required=False,
                     )
```

I can set a blank value with GenericSetup, and my control panel form that interacts with this registry works.
But I can't get GenericSetup to import values from registry.xml for this record. Entering a value TTP and exporting it with GenericSetup yields the following:

```
<registry>
  <record field="display_fields" interface="my.product.interfaces.settings.IMySettings" name="my.product.interfaces.settings.IMySettings.display_fields">
    <field type="plone.registry.field.List">
      <description>The fields that will be displayed in view and edit pages</description>
      <required>False</required>
      <title>Display Fields</title>
    </field>
    <value>
      <element>{'code': u'authors', 'name': u'Authors'}</element>
    </value>
  </record>
</registry>
```

But if I try to import it I get an error!

```
TypeError: ('Could not adapt', None, <InterfaceClass zope.schema._bootstrapinterfaces.IFromUnicode>)
```

That's this line in plone.supermodel.utils "converter = IFromUnicode(field)" and in the debugger I see that the value for 'field' is actually None.

So, what is the proper way to handle registry.xml for datagridfields? Or am I going to have to add records programmatically in setuphandlers.py or something? I'm fairly new to using
the registry and plone.supermodel, and given that the field says None I would not be surprised if my registry.xml is simply wrong.

Comment: Registry had some issues why it could not support complex field types like DGF. Either 1) stop trying 2) be prepared to go long lengths to fix the issue with registry and DGF themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are declaring **code** and **name** as schema.TextLine (unicode) but you are using a string on the registry; try the following:

{u'code': u'authors', u'name': u'Authors'}